# Enabling pecl_http request pool cookie persistence

Tags: php, http, cookies, pecl

I'm trying to enable cookie persistence for a sent of pecl_http HttpRequest objects, sent using the same HttpRequestPool object (if it matters); unfortunately documentation is quite scarce, and despite all my attempts I do not think things work properly.

I have tried both using HttpRequestDataShare (albeit documentation here is *very* scarce) and using the 'cookiestore' request option to point to a file. I still do not see cookies sent back to the server(s) in consecutive requests.

To be clear, by "cookie persistence" I mean that cookies set by the server are automatically stored and re-sent by pecl_http on consecutive requests, without me having to manually handle that (if it comes to it I will, but I am hoping I don't have to do that).

Can anyone point me to a working code sample or application that sends multiple HttpRequest objects to the same server and utilizes pecl_http's cookie persistence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mind that the request pool tries to send all requests in parallel, so they cannot know cookies not yet received of course. E.g.:

```
<?php

$url = "http://dev.iworks.at/ext-http/.cookie.php";

function cc($a) { return array_map("current", array_map("current", $a)); }

$single_req = new HttpRequest($url);

printf("1st single request cookies:\n");
$single_req->send();
print_r(cc($single_req->getResponseCookies()));

printf("waiting 1 second...\n");
sleep(1);

printf("2nd single request cookies:\n");
$single_req->send();
print_r(cc($single_req->getResponseCookies()));

printf("1st pooled request cookies:\n");
$pooled_req = new HttpRequestPool(new HttpRequest($url), new HttpRequest($url));
$pooled_req->send();
foreach ($pooled_req as $req) {
    print_r(cc($req->getResponseCookies()));
}

printf("waiting 1 second...\n");
sleep(1);

printf("2nd pooled request cookies:\n");
$pooled_req = new HttpRequestPool(new HttpRequest($url), new HttpRequest($url));
$pooled_req->send();
foreach ($pooled_req as $req) {
    print_r(cc($req->getResponseCookies()));
}

printf("waiting 1 second...\n");
sleep(1);

printf("now creating a request datashare\n");
$pooled_req = new HttpRequestPool(new HttpRequest($url), new HttpRequest($url));
$s = new HttpRequestDataShare();
$s->cookie = true;
foreach ($pooled_req as $req) {
    $s->attach($req);
}

printf("1st pooled request cookies:\n");
$pooled_req->send();
foreach ($pooled_req as $req) {
    print_r(cc($req->getResponseCookies()));
}

printf("waiting 1 second...\n");
sleep(1);

printf("2nd pooled request cookies:\n");
$pooled_req->send();
foreach ($pooled_req as $req) {
    print_r(cc($req->getResponseCookies()));
}
```